# Incorporating uploaded data into a callback in Dash

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

First I made a simple app with fixed data:

```
import base64
import datetime
import io

import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ['css stylesheet test.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')

text = 'Col1'
vals = df.groupby([text]).size()
available_indicators = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5', 'Col6', 'Col7']
status_vals = df['Status'].unique()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.H1("Welcome to the Dashboard"),
        html.P("Learning Dash is fun!")
             ], ),
    dcc.Graph(id='donut-with-slider'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='Category',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in available_indicators],
        value='Col1'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='Status',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in status_vals],
        value='Filled'),
    dcc.Slider(
        id='year-slider',
        min=df['Year'].min(),
        max=df['Year'].max(),
        value=df['Year'].max(),
        marks={str(Year): str(Year) for Year in df['Year'].unique()},
        step=None
            ),
        ])

@app.callback(
    Output('donut-with-slider', 'figure'),
    Input('year-slider', 'value'),
    Input('Category', 'value'),
    Input('Status', 'value'))
def update_figure(selected_year, Category, Status):
    df2 = df[df.Year == selected_year]
    df3 = df2[df2.Status == Status]
    text = Category
    vals = df3.groupby([text]).size()
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=vals.index.values, values=vals, hole=0.3)])

    fig.update_layout(transition_duration=500)
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

And all is well. What I'm struggling to do is adapt this so that data can be uploaded using dcc.Upload, and then incorporated into the donut-with-slider plot so it remains interactive. Importantly there is also a lot of pandas legwork that has to go into cleaning up the uploaded data. This is what I have so far that is not working (updated to try to send to json, but still getting same list error):

```
#ideally I wouldn't need to start this way, with the last 
#saved data, because uploaded files might have new 
#values, but I can't think of how else to do this
df = pd.read_csv('Most_Recent_Version.csv')

text = 'Col1'
vals = df.groupby([text]).size()
available_indicators = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5', 'Col6', 'Col7']
status_vals = df['Status'].unique()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '60px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },
        multiple=True
    ),
    html.Div([
    html.H1("Welcome to the Dashboard"),
    html.P("Learning Dash is so interesting!!")
         ], ),
    dcc.Graph(id='donut-with-slider'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='Category',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in available_indicators],
        value='Col1'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='Status',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in status_vals],
        value='Filled'),
    dcc.Slider(
        id='year-slider',
        min=df['Year'].min(),
        max=df['Year'].max(),
        value=df['Year'].max(),
        marks={str(Year): str(Year) for Year in df['Year'].unique()},
        step=None),
        html.Div(id='output-data-upload'),    
    ])
@app.callback(
Output('intermediate-value', 'children'),
[Input('upload-data', 'filename'), Input('upload-data', 'contents')])
def parse_contents(contents, filename):
    if contents is not None:
        content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')
        decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
        try:
            if 'csv' in filename:
                #if they upload a csv, the file is already clean
                df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded), header=0) 
                
            elif 'xls' in filename:
                df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded), sheet_name=tabs, header=1, usecols='B:AC') 
                #lines and lines of pandas cleanup
                #save new Most_Recent_Version.csv                
                cleaned.to_csv('Most_Recent_Version.csv', index=None)
                return cleaned.to_json(date_format='iso', orient='split')

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return html.Div([
                'There was an error processing this file.'
        
            ])   
    
    else:
        return dash.no_update

@app.callback(
    Output('donut-with-slider', 'figure'), 
    [Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
    Input('upload-data', 'filename')],
    Input('Category', 'value'),
    Input('Status', 'value'),
    Input('year-slider', 'value'))
def update_figure(contents, filename, Category, Status, selected_year):
    if json_updated_data is not None:
        dff = pd.read_json(json_updated_data, orient='split')
    
        df2 = dff[dff.Year == selected_year]
        df3 = df2[df2.Status == Status]
        text = Category
        vals = df3.groupby([text]).size()
        fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=vals.index.values, values=vals, hole=0.3)])
        fig.update_layout(transition_duration=500)
        return fig



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

In addition to callback where I commented about the list type, the error it's throwing lies with `content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')` in parse_data(): AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Maybe some of this is connected, why is everything constantly getting converted to a list? What am I missing here? I tried having a second callback to update the output but that didn't seem to help either.

Comment: You inputs are in the wrong order - in the callback decorator `year-slider` is in the last spot, but in the function parameters it's third. AFAIK, callback parameters get assigned positionally.

Comment: I can't find where `contents` is defined. What data type is it?

Comment: The {contents} type question confuses me too, since I pulled that from the docs of dash (https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/upload) and I'm not sure in what way the inputs could be in a different order, since I thought the output had to be first and after that the inputs in the callback match the order they're defined in the layout.

Comment: `Input` Parameters should be in the same order in the `@app.callback` decorator as they are in the function that it decorates. For you they are in the right order in the first example, but in the wrong order in the second.

Comment: Ah I see, I think I've fixed that now (above) but still getting the same error about contents being a list.